# Rotationally symmetrical shapes with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a rotationally symmetrical shape, without having to write out duplicate points. This way I can change a single point and the whole shape changes. However there is something very wrong happening, see the tips of the points on the four tipped figure. They should not look like that, they should look like the one manually created to the right.

This problem seems to be caused by the line thickness being entirely on the outside of the specified points. This means that when they are flipped via xscale=-1 they do not center properly How can I fix this? Maybe there is an entirely different way to go about what I am trying to do? You can see how much shorter the code for the first drawing is than the second, and the second one is only a quarter of its full code for the sake of this example.

[image: bad joints]

```
\documentclass[crop, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlinecolor}{m}{
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {1} {black}{}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {2} {white}{}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {3} {black}{}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlinethickness}{m}{
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {1} {1.5pt}{}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {2} {0.5pt}{}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {3} {0.1pt}{}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \c in {1, 2, 3}{%draw first with a black thick line, draw next with a medium white line, draw again with a black thin line
    \foreach \k in {-1, 1}{%draw the actual and mirror of the shape
    \foreach \i in {0, 90, 180, 270}{%draw the shape radially four times
        \draw[xscale=\k,rotate=\i,line width=\getlinethickness{\c},color=\getlinecolor{\c},fill=black,anchor=center]
        (0,1) --
        (0.2,0.4) -- 
        (0.2,0) --
        (0,0) --
        cycle;
    }}}%


    \draw[color=red, line width=0.05pt] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

    \draw[color=red, line width=0.05pt] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);

    \draw[color=blue, line width=0.05pt] (-1.2,1) -- (1.2,1);


\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.25in}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %draw the black outline
    \draw[line width=\getlinethickness{1},color=\getlinecolor{1},fill=black,anchor=center]
    (0,1) --
    (0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0.2,0) --
    (0,0) --
    (-0.2,0) --
    (-0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0,1) --
    cycle;
    
    %draw a white hairline
    \draw[line width=\getlinethickness{2},color=\getlinecolor{2},fill=black,anchor=center]
    (0,1) --
    (0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0.2,0) --
    (0,0) --
    (-0.2,0) --
    (-0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0,1) --
    cycle;

    %used to cover up middle seams
    \draw[line width=\getlinethickness{3},color=\getlinecolor{3},fill=black,anchor=center]
    (0,1) --
    (0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0.2,0) --
    (0,0) --
    (-0.2,0) --
    (-0.2,0.4) -- 
    (0,1) --
    cycle;

    \draw[color=red, line width=0.05pt] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

    \draw[color=red, line width=0.05pt] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);

    \draw[color=blue, line width=0.05pt] (-1.2,1) -- (1.2,1);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Additionally, there is some problem with standalone cropping tikz poorly, I had to specify a manual border. Without it the tips of the shape would be cropped off. If anyone knows a solution to this that would be great.

Comment: About `standalone` not cropping TikZ pictures properly, I recently found that you have to declare your document class like this `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, and the issue is solved. Naturally, you can then avoid `\usepackage{tikz}`, afterwards.

Comment: Yes I read about that, but upon trying it I found that it doesn't actually work properly. My image is still cropped at the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) TikZ library might be of some use to you here.  It allows you to manipulate paths, including transforming them and rejoining them.

Here's how I would code your shape, starting with the basic path.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582869/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlinecolor}{m}{
  \clist_item:nn {black, white, black} {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlinethickness}{m}{
  \clist_item:nn {1.5pt, 0.5pt, 0.1pt} {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Save the basic shape
\path[spath/save=path] (.2,.2) -- (.2,.4) -- (0,1);

\tikzset{
  % Clone it for the next piece
  spath/clone={reflected path}{path},
  % Reflect it in the y-axis
  spath/transform={reflected path}{xscale=-1},
  % Reverse the reflected path
  spath/reverse={reflected path},
  % Join it to the original path
  spath/join with={path}{reflected path},
  % Clone the combined path for rotating
  spath/clone={path 90}{path},
  % Rotate the new clone
  spath/transform={path 90}{rotate=90},
  % Join it to the original path
  spath/join with={path}{path 90},
  % Clone the newly combined path
  spath/clone={path 180}{path},
  % Rotate it 180
  spath/transform={path 180}{rotate=180},
  % Join it to the original path
  spath/join with={path}{path 180},
  % Weld all the components together so that they join nicely
  spath/spot weld={path},
  % Close the path
  spath/close={path}
}

\foreach \c in {1, 2, 3}{
  \draw[
    line width=\getlinethickness{\c},
    color=\getlinecolor{\c},
    fill=black,
    spath/restore=path
  ];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've added comments about what each key is doing.  You can look at the documentation for more detail (though I appear to have forgotten to document the `join with` key - it just puts one path after another).

Here's what that produces:

[image: Picture with rotational symmetry built from an edge]

I've also changed your `\getlinewidth` and colour macros slightly to use comma separated lists internally which might make it simpler to maintain.

The issue with `standalone` is *probably* because the sharp corners protrude farther than the calculation of the bounding box accounts for.  When it adds a path to calculate the bounding box then TikZ/PGF takes into account the current line width and adds a little extra, but that isn't enough for sharp corners (since these can potentially protrude arbitrarily far).  You can add a little to the bounding box at the end of a tikzpicture fairly automatically, or just add to the `border` option as you do in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there is an entirely different way to go about what I am trying to do?

while you are waiting for some of the TikZ-team, here is something completely different.  If you are happy to try `lualatex` you could use [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) instead.  Here is one way to make shapes created from reflection and rotation.  You need to compile this example with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path unit, cross; 
    unit = ((1,0) -- (0.4, 0.2) -- (0.2, 0.2)) scaled 42;
    cross = for i = 0 upto 3:
        unit rotated 90i &
        reverse unit reflectedabout (origin, point infinity of unit) rotated 90i &
    endfor cycle;
    
    % linejoin := mitered;
    filldraw cross withpen pencircle scaled 1.8;
    draw cross withcolor white;

    path axis;
    axis = (left--right) scaled 50;
    draw axis withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 3/4 red;
    draw axis rotated 90 withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 3/4 red;
    draw axis shifted 42 up withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 3/4 blue;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

and you should get a PDF with something like this:
[image: black cross with white lines round the edge]

### Notes

- the `&` operator in MP is used to concatenate things.  Here I have used it to construct the path `cross` from the `unit` path rotated and reflected.
- in MP you can put loops "in line" -- languages like Scala also do this
- the only trick I've used is to `filldraw` the shape with a big thick pen, and then draw it again with a default pen using white to create the internal border.
- if you prefer the ends sharply pointed instead of rounded, then uncomment `linejoin := mitered`.